# Is there a way to make HTML labels work with form elements without IDs?

Tags: html

For example, given:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input id="username" name="username" value="" />
```

When you click on the "Username:" label, focus goes to the corresponding form field.

Without resorting to JavaScript, is it possible to have the same behavior when the form field has no ID?

Real world example where this will be an issue is for dynamically constructed forms, where you may add similar fields to a form, or maybe add multiple instances of the same form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the label is associated implicitly with the first input it conatins:

```
<label>Username:
<input name="username" value="" />
</label>
```

From the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element

In fact, I consider nesting the input in the label better-practice; it can be more semantic, and in some cases leads to a better ui, by eliminating non-clickable spaces between radio buttons or check-boxes and their labels.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm considering is appending something to the ID to make it unique. For example, the timestamp:

```
<label for="username-12019734517">Username:</label>
<input id="username-12019734517" name="username" value="" />
```

Comment: You should add this to your question (and delete it as an answer) instead.  Use the edit link under the question to update it.

Comment: But isn't this an answer by itself?

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if there's a true answer to your question, but I'll wait and see. A workaround would be to construct the ids programmatically. So if you have a form that you're going to duplicate, give each instance its own name and id like `form0, form1`, and its inputs ids like `form0_username`, etc.